# How to avoid hover/mouseenter being called again when creating child elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I'm dynamically creating a box inside an element, say A, whenever the user hovers over A. The box, B, is then moved around with the mouse. B should only appear when the user is hovering over A (i.e. it is removed on mouseleave).

Unfortunately, if I dynamically create elements inside B, when the mouse moves over them, the hover event is called again (creating a new B). This issue seems to happen when I dynamically create B's children on the mouse move. At first I thought it was to do with bubbling, and needing to delegate, but now I feel it has to do with the fact I'm emptying the box and filling it again (thereby causing the hover event to fire again)?

This example illustrates what I'm having a problem with:

https://jsfiddle.net/shzy6gtx/

```
function positionBox(element, position) {
    element.css({
        top: position - element.parent().offset().top - 10,
    });
    element.empty();
    jQuery('<span />').appendTo(element).text(position);    
}

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    if ($('#theBox').length <= 0)
        return;
    positionBox($('#theBox'), e.pageY);
});

$('.hover').hover(function(e) {
    var innerBox = jQuery('<div />', {
        id: 'theBox',
        class: 'inner',
    }).appendTo(this);
    positionBox(innerBox, e.pageY);
}, function(e) {
    $('#theBox').remove();
});
```

This is how it should work (without the dynamically created `span` tags):

https://jsfiddle.net/dffyt6gx/

If this is something I can't solve, how else can this be accomplished?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `.hover()` for that, as it will be called on `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`.

Comment: There's lot of wrong things in your code. Just a question before, what's that for? do you expect to have a click that'll fix that .inner where clicked?

Comment: @Roko Thank you for your kind and productive words words. Yes.

Comment: Do you actually really want to (or have to) create the position label a zillion times while the mouse is moving?

Comment: Want, yes. Need, no. The contents of the inner box are more complex than the trivial example I included here.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem in fact looks like both:

1. an event-bubbling problem.
2. a problem with the repeated rapid creation of the position-span
   My theory is that when the label is destroyed with `.empty()` while the mouse is hovering the position label, and it is not added back again fast enough, this will be considered as another mouse-enter event.

Now 1. can be solved by simply adding

```
if (e.delegateTarget != e.target)
        return;
```

to the hover event handler. You can observe notice that the problem occurs way less often.

For 2.

- One simple solution would be to **not** create the label again every time the mouse (and B) are moved.
  have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/IARI/w8y1y3vt/

  If for some reason you want to or have to create the element(s) inside B every time this wont help. However if it is possible not to recreate them I would advise you to do so, if only for performance reasons.
- If simply checking, whether B exists is an option for you, that would solve it as well while allowing you to recreate the position-label - https://jsfiddle.net/IARI/shzy6gtx/6/

Comment: The bug still occurs unfortunately. Try wiggling the mouse a little. Doesn't happen as often, but still occurs.

Comment: Your comment about the `.empty()` is interesting, however the `span` object should be contained within the outer box (that has the `hover()`), meaning it shouldn't generate another `mouseenter`. That's what I'm wondering about, and the real crux of the matter. +1 for considering it, thank you.

Comment: @Druckles is it ok for you to check if B exists? consider the latest edit.

Comment: Aha, what a simply hack. Yes, that appears to work. I'm still curious why it fires a new `mouseenter` though.

Comment: yep, a simple quick hack indeed - but I'm curious too, I'm not sure my theory is correct but I haven't found a better solution yet :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83923/discussion-between-iari-and-druckles).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this can help you but you are assigning a #id to each div and trying to work with those elements an #id must be unique in the DOM.

```
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    if ($('.inner').length <= 0)
        return;
    positionBox($('.inner'), e.pageY);
});

$('.hover').hover(function(e) {
    var innerBox = jQuery('<div />', {
        id: 'theBox',
        class: 'inner',
    }).appendTo(this).click(function(e) {
    });
    positionBox(innerBox, e.pageY);
}, function(e) {
    $('.inner').remove();
});
```

Maybe this can give you a clue

Added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Slico/bkznbp4e/)

Comment: I am removing the object again. The fact that it is not the only element with that ID is the problem. I've clarified my question to better clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the handler out.

```
**$('body').on('click','#theBox', function(e){
    alert('event handler'); });**

$('.hover').hover(function(e) {
    var innerBox = jQuery('<div />', {
        id: 'theBox',
        class: 'inner',
    }).appendTo(this);
    jQuery('<span />').appendTo(innerBox).text('number');
    positionBox(innerBox, e.pageY);
}, function(e) {
    $('#theBox').remove();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to leave the click handler in there. I left it in by mistake - it's not directly related to the problem.